# How to pass discount amount to Authorize.Net

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net

I would like pass discount(Coupon) amount to Authorize .net in C#, 
when i pass discount amount in line items with negative value($-30), i am getting error. without discount code everything working fine

Example:

```
1   Item1   10  N   US $24.95   US $249.50

Discount:       US $-30.00
Total:      US $219.50

var transactionRequest = new transactionRequestType
            {
                transactionType = transactionTypeEnum.authCaptureTransaction.ToString(),   // charge the card
                amount = order.LineItems.Sum(od => od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity),
                lineItems = lineItems,
                order = new orderType { invoiceNumber = order.Orderid, description = order.OrderDescription },
                customer = new customerDataType { id = order.customerdetails.Customerid, email = order.customerdetails.CustomerEmail },
                currencyCode = order.CurrencyCode
            };
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You have a string input and must parse string to a number value :

```
string input = "1   Item1   10  N   US $24.95   US $249.50";

string[] array = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

decimal amount = decimal.Parse(array[7], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency);

decimal discount = amount - 30;
```

Comment: I have discount amount value separatly,  i want to pass it  with line items.

Comment: Explain better.